# What happened to the Inductosyn?

Tags: position-sensor

From what I have read the Inductosyn has incredible accuracy (~3um) and repeatability (~600nm) yet it seems to be phased out for position sensing applications and nobody talks about it anymore. What was the drawback? Cost, speed, reliability? If anyone knows I would greatly appreciate it, I've spent days looking but it seems like it was already superseded by optical encoders before the internet.

http://www.ruhle.com/rotary%20transducers.htm

https://www.maccon.com/rotary-linear-encoders/magnetic-encoders/inductosyn.html

The link below provides a great comparison for Encoders vs Resolvers which is similar and I understand, but the Inductosyn doesn't have the accuracy drawback.

https://ormec.com/Portals/ormec/files/Services/Applications/ApplicationNotes/EncoderVsResolver.pdf

1999 website that goes over inductosyns

http://what-when-how.com/electric-motors/linear-and-rotary-inductosyns-electric-motors/

Comment: question seems fine to me

Comment: Questions seems fine to me too since it is more about comparing technologies than products.

Comment: The normal behavior is to write or call the sales partner, but I hope you have deep pockets. ;). innovation@celeramotion.com

Comment: https://www.celeramotion.com/zettlex/product/mini-ultra-incoder-37mm/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No sure answers but I can postulate a few possibilities:

1. Optical encoders are in a class of technology completely different from resolvers and InductoSyn. That makes them easier to differentiate. If the low resolution of resolvers compared to optical encoders is widely known, it's going to cause more people to just pick the optical encoder rather than the InductoSyn which is more difficult to differentiate from the resolver.
2. The InductoSyn disc sounds like it would be more expensive to make than a quadrature optical encoder disc since it requires two discs while the optical encoder only requires one.
3. It could be the case that magnetic encoders, rather than optical encoders, supplanted Inductosyn . The description of the InductoSyn sounds a LOT like the magnetic encoders I use at work, down to the available pole counts and interpolation factors, except that instead of a hall sensor it uses induction. This is the possibility I lean towards the most since optical encoders and magnetic/inductive encoders have different advantages and disadvantages so it doesn't make too much sense for one to supplant the other. Magnetic and inductive encoders, on the other hand, seem to share most of the same advantages and disadvantages, but induction sensors are more complex (and therefore expensive) than magnetic sensors. Though I suppose they are immune to demagnetization.

Comment: Yea taking a broad look again with fresh eyes it is now an extremely niche solution due to all of the other encoders now available. My solution requires: Position Feedback -> Linear -> 100mm+ length -> Magnetic Type -> Induction Type -> Accurate <3um, which naturally leads me to think of the inductosyn as the only thing in town since that is all I'm looking at (radiation environment). It just so happened that the Inductosyn is an old tech that satisfies my requirements and better options for the majority have edged it out of the limelight.

Comment: @TranscendentUsername Yeah, radiation seems like something that induction would have an advantage over magnetic.

Answer (score 1):

The outsourcing of manufacturing to Asia and ease of interfacing already digital incremental sensors possibly had a significant role.

I noticed the biggest shift correlated with increased integration (74 shifting to ASICs) Early ASICs were not mixed signal like now. Also incremental systems seemed easy to copy where Inductosyn is extensively copyright, patent protected.

PS brushless resolvers from the 70, 80's are very repeatable and low noise. Modern equivalents have a hard time replacing them unless you go to extremely expensive military grade units.

The article above references the ratiometric interpolation resolver interface and its limitations. Most machinetool manfufacturers used a phase difference measurement which was easier to do digitally.

There is always lag in a digital servo system, and having a defined time window eases some aspects of programming in a real-time scenario.

Incremental systems have to avoid missing counts, absolute measures have to measure before the transition to the next cycle.

Just different engineering tradeoffs.